# Defining DLQ for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a lambda subscribing to an SNS topic. The frequency of the notifications are low but the messages are important. In the "Debugging and error handling" section for lambda (in aws console page where we define lambda) I'm seeing an option to define a DLQ. In my scenario, is it advisable to create a DLQ?

Thanks,

Comment: It's a very good idea to define this but understand that you need to deal with it then. Any messages that make it there will eventually time out and be deleted so if the messages are important then you might need **another** Lambda to handle the DLQ messages.  And, of course, what if processing a message from the DLQ fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely.

If you say that '*messages are important*' then it is highly recommended that you use the DLQ.

How you deal with the messages that reach DLQ is another problem, but atleast you have the messages that the Lambda was not able to process and that make it to DLQ.

Consider this scenario, that the message was perfectly fine but Lambda was not able to process that within the timeout duration and eventually timesout and a lot of messages reach DLQ because of that. Now if you see this behavior then you can simply increase the Lambda timeout or the memory footprint and retry the processing of messages in DLQ and you might succeed in this attempt